# Why is my user scoped custom dimension changing on past hits?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

Is a user scoped custom dimensions supposed to change for past hits? For example, I have a custom dimension for PromoCode which tracks the promo code that a user came to the site with (ie: through an ad/offer). I have the dimension set up in Tag Manager like so:

Google Analytics Pageview Tag (custom dimensions section):

```
Index    Dimension Value
2        {{ValidPromoCode}}
```

Variables: `{{varPromoCode}}`

```
Type: URL
Component Type: Query
Query Key: promocode
```

Then I have some javascript in the actual site to grab the promocode and set it as a cookie which is checked in the `{{ValidPromoCode}}` var - so it checks for a promocode in the URL, if it's there it changes the dimension value to that, otherwise it uses the cookie value:

```
function() {
    //parse promocode value from cookie string
    var promoCode = document.cookie.substring( document.cookie.indexOf("promocode=") + 10, document.cookie.indexOf( ";", document.cookie.indexOf("promocode=") + 10 ) );
    if( typeof {{varPromoCode}} == "undefined" ) {
        if ( document.cookie.indexOf("promocode") >= 0 ) {
            return promoCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        //docs say a query var will return the full querystring if the parameter
        //is not found, from my experience it returns undefined. 
        //simple check for querystring here anyway (if it has = its a querystring)
        if ( {{varPromoCode}}.indexOf("=") == -1 ) {
            return {{varPromoCode}};
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all working as expected. Using tag manager debug and google analytics debugger the proper values are set in all scenarios when the hits are sent. (ie: changing the promocode, deleting the cookie, no promocode etc).

The problem is (and maybe it's not a problem, but a feature)... When I use one promocode, say `TEST16` then I do some pageviews, trigger some events then go check in analytics a few minutes later, there are my pageviews/events with the `TEST16` promocode attached... However, if I then change the promocode to say `T35T16` and go do some different pageviews/events... Then check analytics a few minutes later the first code `TEST16` is nowhere in sight and the pages/events I hit now show the `T35T16` promocode...

Is this how user scope is supposed to work? I thought no analytics data/changes ever propagated backwards in time?

I want the promocode to follow the user indefinitely, but I also want it to change if I change the value (ie: they clicked a new ad) without affecting their past hits/promo values.

Should I be using session scope? Or should I change my implementation somehow?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I meant to put in an answer then I left for lunch...but you are correct. The value is session based. And since promocode in the real world (outside the simple test I did) are only changed with ads/campaigns and a new campaign starts a new session there is actually not an issue here anymore.

Comment: I found that info further down the docs then I had initially read...silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Just noticed that nyuens answer had covered this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historical data doesn't get changed once it has been processed. User-scoped values apply to the current and future hits only. For example, if you have a user-scope dimension of `"logged in or not"` (with values of `true` or `false`), then if for one session the last value is `false`, then that will be the value for that CD for the whole session. In the next session, that value is again `false` as it applies to future hits. If the final value then changes to `true`, then that's what gets applied to that CD for the whole session. So what you're seeing is the value changing for that particular session only.

[cf. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827#processing]

Comment: thanks...I saw that further down the docs when I re-read them but couldn't answer yet then went to lunch...I've accepted yours instead.